# iOS auto login, usserdefaults not working

Tags: ios, swift3

1 I keep on getting this error in my code, but it worked before. tested and working.

> 1.Argument labels '(string:, _:)' do not match any available overloads
>
> 2.Overloads for 'URL' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (string: String, relativeTo: URL?), (fileURLWithPath: String, relativeTo: URL?), (fileURLWithPath: String, isDirectory: Bool), (dataRepresentation: Data, relativeTo: URL?, isAbsolute: Bool), (resolvingAliasFileAt: URL, options: URL.BookmarkResolutionOptions)?

any help please?

this is my code

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var homeWebveiw: WKWebView!

let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let username = defaultValues.string(forKey: "username")
    let password = defaultValues.string(forKey: "password")
    print(defaultValues.string(forKey: "username"))
    print(defaultValues.string(forKey: "password"))
    print(defaultValues.string(forKey: "loggedin"))

    let url = URL(string :"https://www.twsb.co.za/mobile_app/index.php?username=" + username! + "&password=" + password!, "&to=home")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
    homeWebveiw.load(requestObj)
```

Comment: I think this never worked before. You should use "+" before "&to=home", instead of a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `,` where a `+` should be (after `+ password!` in your URL initializer):

```
let url = URL(string :"https://www.twsb.co.za/mobile_app/index.php?username=" + username! + "&password=" + password! + "&to=home")
```

By the way, UserDefaults is not a secure place to store the user's username and password. If you want your user's login details to be secure (and you probably should) then you should think about using the iOS Keychain to store them.

You can find the Keychain API documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services

Comment: thank you this took the error away but it throws out a result nil and does not load the url